# Use userdefaults on a struct

Tags: ios, string, struct, swift3, nsuserdefaults

I am manually entering data into a struct. However the struct is not saving the data. I tried to use userdefaults but it's not working. I want the data to appear on the label `benCarson` at all times if it's in the struct `bad`.

ViewController 1

```
struct bad {
    static var mm = [String]()
}
```

ViewController 2

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var benCarson: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        benCarson.text = ViewController.bad.mm.map { " \($0)" }.joined(separator:"\n")
    }
}
```

Comment: It is Swift convention to name your structures starting with an uppercase letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think no need for struct just use the UserDefaults and it will work

**For Save**

```
let mm = ["adsa", "safds", "twer", "qwer", "dfas"]
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(mm, forKey: "SavedStringArray")
defaults.synchronize()
```

**For Retrieve**

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let myarray = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "SavedStringArray") ?? [String]()
benCarson.text = myarray.map { " \($0)" }.joined(separator:"\n")
```

Comment: No need to force synchronize

Comment: Btw Swift is a type inferred language, there is no need to specify the array type when using the nil coalescing operator. Just pass an empty array `?? [ ]`